# Can I view the sales reports/information from Android Market for my apps somewhere?

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to download the sales information for my Android apps?

For the iTunes store, Apple provides a tool for the same on [iTunes Connect Sales and Trends Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20111017180641/http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf).

Are there similar tools for the Android apps' sales data? OR are there any external tools? I noticed that Appmonger is an app that provides the same. Are there any other external tools/sites?

Comment: This is only marginally on-topic as questions about the Market from a developers perspective are off-topic. (Check out the proposal for [App Stores](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores), where this would be on-topic.) However, since you're asking about, and there may be, an app for your device that would do what you need, I think it's good enough to stay.

Answer (score 0):

> - **Earnings Reports**: Generated near the beginning of the month.
> - **Estimated Sales Reports**: Generated daily by adding all transactions that were CHARGED or REFUNDED recently to the current month's file. It can take several days for all new transactions to appear.
>
> **Note**: Financial data is based on Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

From [Play Console Help - Download sales and payout reports](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2482017)